# CodeIgniter: how to load dynamic content within a larger page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic

Keeping it simple, let's say I have a page that has a user-specific menu and a user-specific header, and then the page itself is user-specific.

I can load everything into `$data` and then into something like this within my controller:

```
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('sidebar', $data);
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

But this doesn't not look like the best way to do it.

Is there a way to prepare an element completely, and separately and just include that into the primary controller? I think such a way would keep the code cleaner.

Perhaps we can use call functions within the controller? If so, how can we restrict those specific functions from being accessible as `page/function`?

Answer (score 0):

I see there few questions. Let me try to answer. 
You can pass third argument set to false in view file loading, so instead output is sent to browser, it will be returned string. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::view).

Secondly, you can call other methods of existing class in method with next syntax:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['header'] = $this->page_header();
    $data['sidebar'] = $this->page_sidebar();
    $this->load->view('page', $data);
    //so in view of page view file you just output header and sidebar
}

protected function page_header()
{
    $data['data_of_header'] = $this->Some_header_data_model->get_all();
    $this->load->view('header', $data, TRUE);
}

private function page_sidebar()
{
    $data['data_of_sidebar'] = $this->Some_sidebar_data_model->get_all();
    $this->load->view('sidebar', $data, TRUE);
}
```

Pay attention on [visibility keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) and their meaning.

You can search and check github repositories for some template libraries which will make it easier for you.